# cURL not sending POST data, but works properly in terminal

Tags: php, cordova, curl

this is the curl code that works in command line :

```
  $ curl -F file=@/path/to/index.html -u lslkdfmkls@gmail.com -F 'data={"title":"API V1  App","package":"com.alunny.apiv1","version":"0.1.0","create_method":"file"}' https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/apps
```

This is my code :

```
$ch = curl_init();

$data = array("title"=>"sampele title","package"=>"com.fsdlfn.sdfknsdj","version"=>"0.1.0","create_method"=>"file","file"=>"@/path/myfolder/myfile.zip");

$jsdata = json_encode($data);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/app?auth_token='.$token); //got this token already, so using that here .
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsdata);

echo curl_exec($ch);
```

The curl command working in terminal, but the above curl command written in php, returning error :

```
{"error":"no create_method specified: file, remote_repo, or hosted_repo"}
```

What can be the solution?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ch = curl_init();

$data = array("title"=>"sampele title","package"=>"com.fsdlfn.sdfknsdj","version"=>"0.1.0","create_method"=>"file");

$jsdata = json_encode($data);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/app?auth_token='.$token); //got this token already, so using that here .
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('data' => $jsdata, 'file'=>'@/path/myfolder/myfile.zip'));

echo curl_exec($ch);
```

Here's why I made the fixes:

1. `$data` is being `json_encode`d, so cURL will not see the `file` attribute and it'll be sent as a string, rather then reading the file - this is why I put `file` directly in the `POSTFIELDS`
2. The variable `$data` will not cause it to be sent as `data=...` but rather a single string (like `POST`ing XML).