# PhoneGap Build API : CURL Command Line to PHP

Tags: php, cordova, file-upload, curl, syntax-error

I am working on PhoneGap Build API to upload file and create its apk. You can check it here https://build.phonegap.com/docs/write_api

I am facing problem in implementing curl using php. The following curl statement on command line is working fine.

$ curl -F file=@/Users/alunny/index.html -u andrew.lunny@nitobi.com -F 'data={"title":"API V1 App","package":"com.alunny.apiv1","version":"0.1.0","create_method":"file"}' https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/apps

I am getting errors when I try to write this code using php. I have written the following code.

```
$username = "email";
$password = "password";
$target_url = "https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/apps";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
$post = array(
        "file"=>"@www.zip",
        "data"=>json_encode(array("title"=>"My Test App","package"=>"com.alunny.apiv1","version"=>"0.1.0","create_method"=>"file"))
    );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

By running this code, I am getting this error "no create_method specified: file, remote_repo, or hosted_repo "

Please help me solving this issue.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253848/curl-not-sending-post-data-but-works-properly-in-terminal

Comment: Thank you Mike for your help. I got solution using the duplicate you gave me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try shell_exec() function:

```
$cmd = "https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/apps";
$out = shell_exec($cmd);
$data = json_decode($out);
```